# Vector tiles and QGIS 3.14+

Tags: qgis, openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm using QGIS to produce a vector tile dataset for use with OpenLayers (as shown [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html)).

However, although the dataset produced can be opened in QGIS and it renders normally, when using it in OpenLayers it does not show at all.

Other vector tile sources seem to work normally on the same Openlayers webpage (eg [this ArcGIS vector tiles dataset](https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.pbf)). I used 3.14 and 3.16 QGIS versions for producing vector tiles. Can someone point to me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my sample [webpage](http://bytemill.duckdns.org:81/openlayers_examples/). This is the Map definition:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        maxZoom: 20,
        url: 'http://bytemill.duckdns.org:81/VTiles_D/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
//'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf'
      })      

    }) ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([23,39]),
    maxZoom: 20,
    zoom: 10,
  }),
});
```

The commented source url is the one that works.

Tiles used are those produced by QGIS using the 'Write Vector Tiles (XYZ)'. So, I'm asking if there is something in vector tiles production using QGIS that causes Openlayers  not to show any data. Has anyone come across something similar?

(About the two GIS SE accounts issue, I've already followed the 'merge accounts' procedure, I believe I'm waiting for a review)

Comment: Without seeing relevant code and some inofo about nonworking layer, it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: Please reconcile your two logins by following the instructions in [this SE help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: What does this layer contain and where on Earth? What is the projection of the vector tile dataset?

Comment: If the World Basemap tiles work with the same code there is a problem with your tiles.  When read they seem to be producing an array of nulls instead of an array of features.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.